# Passing a script while starting an instance in Amazon EC2

Tags: shell, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud

Is it possible to pass a script while I'm starting an instance? So that the instance will execute that script once its initialized?

```
public static void startInstance(final String instanceId) {
    StartInstancesRequest startRequest = new StartInstancesRequest().withInstanceIds(instanceId);
    logger.info(String.format("Starting instance '%s':...", instanceId));
    ec2.startInstances(startRequest);       
}
```

Any idea? Script will be kind of startup script which I need to execute as soon as the instance is ready. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I introduced the concept of *user-data scripts* in the community Ubuntu AMIs in 2009 (simplified version of some ideas from RightScale):

> http://alestic.com/2009/06/ec2-user-data-scripts

It boils down to:

> **If the instance user-data starts with the two characters `#!` then the instance runs it as the root user on the first boot.**

This feature was later included in the official Ubuntu AMIs in the CloudInit package:

> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit

Amazon now includes the CloudInit package in their own Amazon Linux AMIs:

> http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AmazonLinuxAMIBasics.html

Other distros are welcome to (and may already) include this feature in their AMIs.

Comment: I have been using the cloud init package in Ubuntu canonical images for some time.  It generally works great, however I have seen some rare cases where the script does not execute for some reason, so when your app first starts running you may want to have a sanity check to make sure the script you wanted to run actually executed.  For example, I have my heartbeat script used by elastic load balancer check for certain data on my system that would only be populated by the start-up script before returning a 200 response to the ELB health check.

Comment: That's great! Thanks a lot Eric & Mike...

One more question, after a quick search found out that RunInstances is the method if we want to do it through AWS SDK. Now the question is, what are the differences between RunInstances vs StartInstances ? Thanks again

Comment: @tanzir: On EC2, "run" creates a new instance and "start" takes an existing stopped instance and get it running again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Userdata to pass a script to a new EC2 Instance although I dont know if you can start a pre existing instance and pass it data.

I have a pre configured AMI that has a script saved on the root drive, this script is used to configure the server and download the latest source.

So your request could look like the following:

var runInstance = new RunInstancesRequest();

```
        runInstance.WithImageId("{ami-id}")
            .WithInstanceType("{size}")
            .WithMaxCount(1)
            .WithMinCount(1)
            .WithSecurityGroup("{the security group}")
            .WithKeyName("{your key}")
            .WithUserData(Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userData)));

        ec2.RunInstances(runInstance);
```

The user data can contain either a reference to a script or the script itself.

Comment: It is possible to change the user-data of an instance while it is stopped, but the CloudInit software will not run it when the instance boots up again. The user-data scripts are only run on the first boot of an instance.

Comment: So, if we want to run the script every time we start the instance, there is no way to do that?

Thanks again Eric

Comment: @tanzir: Your user-data script could install a standard boot script that gets run on every boot.