# Create folder automatically in var/www/ directory when new instance launched in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, yii

Whenever new instance launched in my website built in YII framework, It stops working because it has a YII logs folder in var/www/ directory and whenever a new instance launched this folder deleted automatically. I need a solution if new instance launched the folder should create automatically in var/www/ directory. So my website works fine.

Comment: You can pass a script while launching a fresh instance.. something along the lines : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Comment: Hi Nishant. How i will add this script in AWS

Comment: Do we have an additional parameter where i can add this script

Comment: In my case the new instance is creating using ELB system.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078414/passing-a-script-while-starting-an-instance-in-amazon-ec2